# Creating h2o cluster using docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile, h2o, h2o4gpu

We are trying to make a cluster of h20 using docker image what we are using is a ENTRYPOINT command with ip of host machine when we are trying to execute the image it give me the following error(Ip Address not found).Please suggest as we have a demo.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Xmx10g","-jar","h2o-3.22.1.6/h2o.jar","-ip","192.168.29.164","-port","54321","-client"]
```

```
IPv6 stack selected: false
Possible IP Address: eth0 (eth0), 172.17.0.2
Possible IP Address: lo (lo), 127.0.0.1
IP address not found on this machine
```

Comment: Is the address you have provided, the address of the host on which the container is running? And if it is - have you tried using the localhost address as mentioned in the error?

Comment: Generally in Docker you want to set servers to listen on the special 0.0.0.0 "all interfaces" IPv4 address, and you can use a `docker run -p` option if you want to publish it out only to specific host interfaces.  (And generally you do not include host-specific information like IP addresses or user IDs in a Dockerfile; an image should be reusable on multiple hosts.)

Comment: Why do you have "-client" there?  I really doubt you know what that does and actually want that there.  It is only used by Sparkling Water, which is not what you are trying to use.  If you want to bind to all interfaces why set the IP at all?  Or set it to 0.0.0.0.